# nested element inheriting parent Div's margin in ie7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Trying to figure out why in IE7, the nested input element is taking on the margin of the parent div. So in essense the margin is being doubled.

```
    <style>
    <!--
    h1.redsubhead{font-size:14px;}
    .accountInfo,.loginInfo{-moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;background: #EBFBFF; border: 1px solid #8DCAD9;margin-bottom: 30px;padding:10px;}
    #ai_pw_wrap,#li_pw_wrap{border:1px solid #f0f;margin-right: 30px;padding:0;}
    #ai_email_wrap{margin-right:30px;padding:0;}
    .ai_wrap,.li_wrap{float:left;}
    .ai_email_input, .li_email_input,.li_pw_input{width:170px;}
    .ai_pw_input{width:130px;}
    .ai_label,.li_label{font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold;}


    .ai_link,.li_link{font-size: 9px; float:right}
     h1.redsubhead{float:left;}
     #li_btn_wrap{margin-top:10px;float:right;}
     .ai_wrap input{margin:0 !important;}
     .ai_label{margin:0}
    -->
    </style>
    <div class="accountInfo">
      <h1 class="redsubhead">Account Info</h1>
      <a class="ai_link" href="#">Returning Member Login</a>
      <div class="clear"></div>

      <div id="ai_email_wrap" class="ai_wrap">
   <label for="edit-payment-new-card-cc-cardholder" class="ai_label">E-mail: </label><br>
   <input type="text" class="ai_email_input" value="John Doe" size="60" maxlength="128">
      </div>

      <div id="ai_pw_wrap" class="ai_wrap">
   <label for="edit-payment-new-card-cc-cardholder" class="ai_label">Password: </label><br>
   <input type="text" class="ai_pw_input" value="John Doe" size="60" maxlength="128">
      </div>

      <div  id="ai_pwc_wrap" class="ai_wrap">
   <label for="edit-payment-new-card-cc-cardholder" class="ai_label">Password Confirm: </label><br>
   <input type="text" class="ai_pw_input" value="John Doe" size="60" maxlength="128">
      </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="loginInfo hide">
      <h1 class="redsubhead">Login</h1>
      <a class="ai_link" href="#">New User Signup</a>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div id="li_email_wrap" class="li_wrap">
   <label for="edit-payment-new-card-cc-cardholder" class="li_label">E-mail: </label><br>
   <input type="text" class="li_email_input" value="John Doe" size="60" maxlength="128">
      </div>
      <div id="li_pw_wrap" class="li_wrap">
   <label for="edit-payment-new-card-cc-cardholder" class="li_label">Password: </label><br>
   <input type="text" class="li_pw_input" value="John Doe" size="60" maxlength="128">
      </div>
      <div id="li_btn_wrap">
       <input type="image" src="/img/checkout/li_login.png" class="li_submit" value="start" name="submit_order">
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

Any suggestions?? I did find a fix, if I change the margin-right:30px to padding-right:30px. I still want to know why the margin on the nested input is taking on the margin of the parent div.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking at a known bug in IE7 (and, I think, 6) called the ["inherited margin bug"](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/inherited_margin.html).

The first child input of an element with the hasLayout property triggered (for example via zoom:1, a clearfix, setting a height or width) will *inherit the sum of the left margins of its ancestors*.

The workarounds (from [this article](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/inherited_margin.html)) are:

1. (Most common) Set a negative margin-left on the input. That will counteract the inherited margins. Use something like `input {  *margin-left: -30px; }` to only target IE7 and below.
2. Don't use margins on the ancestors of the input.
3. Un-do whatever triggered hasLayout on the parent element of the input.
4. Put an inline element (say, a `<label>`) and some text immediately before the input.
5. Wrap the input in another inline element (`<span>`, `<label>`, whatever).

Comment: Wrapping my input element in <span> solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try applying a display: inline rule to your floated element.

```
.ai_wrap,.li_wrap{float:left; display:inline;}
```

and check again?